# Crashlytics: "MyApp could not be installed at this time" when adding entitlements

Tags: ios, crashlytics, adhoc

I'm trying to distribute a beta version through Fiber/Crashlytics. I've been doing this for ages but this time I'm unable to make it work correctly (iOS9+).

My app uses icloud keyvalue store, IAP and push notifications, so it has an entitlements file. The thing is, when I archive and distribute the app, Crashlytics sends the email with the new version to testers and they are able to install it BUT, as soon as it ends installing, a "…could not be installed at this time" appears and the app deletes itself. In the other hand, if I remove the "code signing entitlements" value from Building Settings, the installation works ok (but icloud and other things aren't working, of course).

What am I doing wrong? Is there a workaround for this situation?

Comment: So… why the negative?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. I'd check to make sure that Xcode is pulling in the correct profile as that is the one that Fabric uses. More info here: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/provisioning-profiles.html#all-about-provisioning-profiles

Comment: Hi Mike. In fact, the profiles are correct. I've tried using automatic and any value combination in code signing identity section from Xcode's build settings. I've even re-created the whole application in another Apple account with identical results. If entitlements are included, beta will fail.

Comment: Hmm, I tried reproducing this and wasn't able to locally. Could you email the device console logs to support(at)fabric(io) and reference this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the entitlements file had something wrong (even when I've never edited it by myself!). I had enabled and disabled the required capabilities trying to fix my problem but it didn't worked until I deleted the entitlements file and forced Xcode to recreate it by enabling capabilities again.

After that, I've hadn't any problem to archive and distribute my beta.

Comment: what is entitlements file ?, can you elaborate more ?, i'm having same problem :(.

Comment: Just look for a file called yourAppName.entitlements by entering "entitlements" in Xcode's Filter (at the bottom of the project navigator) and check if something is wrong. Please note that this configuration file may contain useful info apart from the alleged error and you should make a backup copy before deleting it just in case.